# Input from form doesn't match regex, but hard-coded string does

Tags: php, regex

I'm validating an internationalized name such as `L'étoile`  with this regex:

```
/^[\pL',-.\s]+$/
```

When I capture the input and run it through the regex, there is no match:

```
 <input type="text" name="firstname" value="">
 $value = trim($_POST['firstname']);
 $pattern = "/^[\pL',-.\s]+$/";
 print $value.'<br />';
 print preg_match_all($pattern, $value, $match); 

 This prints:
 L'étoile
 0
```

However when I hard code a string like below it matches just fine.

```
$value = "L'étoile";
$pattern = "/^[\pL',-.\s]+$/";
print $value.'<br />';
print preg_match_all($pattern, $value, $match);     

This prints: 
L'�toile   
1
```

Comment: If unicode characters are present, you have to use the MultiByte extension.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/279170/3885509

Comment: Update your pattern into `"/^[\pL',-.\s]+$/u"` instead of `"/^[\pL',-.\s]+$/"` pass the unicode param within your regex. Check this [your code](https://3v4l.org/hvnpL) and [working code](https://3v4l.org/Rv9uJ)

Comment: @Uchiha ... This did the trick.

Comment: Glad it helped you @Jimski

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the `u` [pattern modifier](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) in your regex:

> **u (PCRE_UTF8)**
>
> This modifier turns on additional functionality of PCRE that is incompatible with Perl. Pattern and subject strings are treated as UTF-8. This modifier is available from PHP 4.1.0 or greater on Unix and from PHP 4.2.3 on win32. UTF-8 validity of the pattern and the subject is checked since PHP 4.3.5. An invalid subject will cause the preg_* function to match nothing; an invalid pattern will trigger an error of level E_WARNING. Five and six octet UTF-8 sequences are regarded as invalid since PHP 5.3.4 (resp. PCRE 7.3 2007-08-28); formerly those have been regarded as valid UTF-8.

I would also recommend single-quoting your pattern instead of double-quoting, to prevent PHP from interpolating things inside the string.

Instead of:

```
preg_match_all("/^[\pL',-.\s]+$/", $value, $match);
```

Use:

```
preg_match_all('/^[\pL\',-.\s]+$/u', $value, $match);
```